# Using Ember Data, but properties on model not rendered

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm just getting started with Ember and Ember Data. I have a really simple service, which is hitting my backend service (written in Node). My service returns two items. In my HTML my two items show, or at least their ID's do. The other properties aren't being rendered.

result:

```
* Hello, 1 !
* Hello, 2 !
```

app.js

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 11
});

App.Grunt = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("grunts", { path: "/grunts" });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('grunts');
    }
});

App.GruntsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Grunt.find();
    }
});
```

index.html

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <div>
        <p>{{outlet}}</p>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="grunts">
    <ul>
        {{#each controller}}
            <li>Hello, {{id}} {{firstName}} {{lastName}}!</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

JSON:

```
{
    "grunts": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "firstName": "Joe",
            "lastName": "Bloggs"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "firstName": "Someone",
            "lastName": "Else"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `RESTAdapter` mapping is underscore -> camelized form.  This mean that if your model's attribute is `firstName`, the server should send JSON containing `first_name`.

To fix this you can either send JSON that looks like this:

```
"grunts": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Joe",
    "last_name": "Bloggs"
  }]
```

Or override the `keyForAttributeName` function in your `RESTSerializer`.
For a one to one mapping you can do:

```
keyForAttributeName: function(type, name) {
  return name;
}
```

Or map a single model like this:

```
adapter.map('App.Grunt', { 
  firstName: { keyName: 'firstName'},
  lastName: { keyName: 'lastName'}
});
```